# Is the class Object in Java a metaclass?

Tags: java, class, object, semantics, metaclass

In Java, the class Object acts as the root for all the other classes that are created. Every new class inherits from Object, so can be Object considered the Metaclass of Java? I suppose there is just one Metaclass in Java, not like Smalltalk or Ruby.

Comment: Object is a class in itself. You can create instances of `Object o = new Object();`

Comment: "Metaclass" doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: `Object` is a class. A class is a meta-object. `Class` is a 'meta-class' in Java.